# How to view spin.js on modal

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, spinner

my spinner is not working and not showing. This is what I've tried so far. It doesnt even show loading, please need help, no error nothing on console.

http://jsfiddle.net/D6rD6/354/

Please need help...

I just want to fill a spinner on `modal-body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
document.getElementById("#spinner_center");
```

call is returning null because of a syntax mistake within the selector string. Update it like so:

```
document.getElementById("spinner_center");
```